# How do I pause a requestAnimationFrame and resume on specific time (in React)?

Tags: reactjs, timer, requestanimationframe

I am making a timer hook in React, but I want the ability to start and pause the timer. I'm using requestAnimationFrame so I can get the percentage of the progress.

My code so far:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

interface TimeConfig {
  invokeStart?: boolean;
}

/**
 *
 * @param time Time in milliseconds
 */
export const useTimer = (
  time: number,
  { invokeStart = false }: Partial<TimeConfig> = {}
) => {
  const raf = useRef<number | null>(null);
  const rafActive = useRef<boolean>(false);
  const rafStartTime = useRef<number | null>(null);

  const [elapsed, setElapsed] = useState(0);

  const tick: FrameRequestCallback = useCallback(
    (timestamp) => {
      if (rafActive.current) {
        if (rafStartTime.current === null) rafStartTime.current = timestamp;

        const elapsed = timestamp - rafStartTime.current;

        setElapsed(Math.min(elapsed, time));

        if (elapsed < time) {
          raf.current = requestAnimationFrame(tick);
        }
      }
    },
    [time, elapsed]
  );

  const start = useCallback(() => {
    if (!rafActive.current) {
      rafActive.current = true;
      raf.current = requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    }
  }, [tick]);

  const pause = useCallback(() => {
    if (rafActive.current) {
      rafActive.current = false;
      raf.current && cancelAnimationFrame(raf.current);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (invokeStart) {
      start();
    }
  }, [invokeStart, start]);

  return { start, pause, elapsed };
};
```

I know the timestamp returned from the requestAnimationFrame callback is de timestamp since the page is loaded. But what is a good practice to pause and play in this way.